# Show modified strings that appear more than once

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a Query which cuts off domain suffixes for every row, e.g. google.com -> google or google.co.uk -> google

The query is as follows

```
SELECT id,domain, 
CASE 
WHEN LENGTH(domain) - LENGTH(REPLACE(domain, '.', '')) = 1 THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(domain), LOCATE('.', REVERSE(domain)) + 1, 1000))
WHEN LENGTH(domain) - LENGTH(REPLACE(domain, '.', '')) = 2 THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(domain), LOCATE('.', REVERSE(domain)) + 1, 1000))), LOCATE('.', REVERSE(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(domain), LOCATE('.', REVERSE(domain)) + 1, 1000)))) + 1, 1000))

END as Keydomain
FROM sites
```

Now I want to display all modified domains that occur more than once. How can I do that? Thanks for helping me out ;)

Comment: honestly, you should do such things with a script :)

Comment: =), well, I have to admit that I'm not that good in SQL or programming at all...I don't think that I 1. could write a script and 2. could explain the scripts to others so that they can use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
GROUP BY Keydomain
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

to your query.

**EDIT:**

> Could you tell me if there is a way to list the complete domains one by one with your addition?

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN LENGTH(domain) - LENGTH(REPLACE(domain, '.', '')) = 1 THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(domain), LOCATE('.', REVERSE(domain)) + 1, 1000))
WHEN LENGTH(domain) - LENGTH(REPLACE(domain, '.', '')) = 2 THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(domain), LOCATE('.', REVERSE(domain)) + 1, 1000))), LOCATE('.', REVERSE(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(domain), LOCATE('.', REVERSE(domain)) + 1, 1000)))) + 1, 1000))
END as Keydomain
FROM sites
GROUP BY Keydomain
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) d1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT id, domain,
CASE 
WHEN LENGTH(domain) - LENGTH(REPLACE(domain, '.', '')) = 1 THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(domain), LOCATE('.', REVERSE(domain)) + 1, 1000))
WHEN LENGTH(domain) - LENGTH(REPLACE(domain, '.', '')) = 2 THEN REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(domain), LOCATE('.', REVERSE(domain)) + 1, 1000))), LOCATE('.', REVERSE(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(domain), LOCATE('.', REVERSE(domain)) + 1, 1000)))) + 1, 1000))
END as Keydomain
FROM sites
) d2
ON d1.Keydomain = d2.Keydomain
```

Comment: That was easy! Thanks. Could you tell me if there is a way to list the complete domains one by one with your addition?